# Use arrays as keys for a dict

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, google-apps-script

**Note**:

Asking about alternative methods for performing a task is not a matter of opinion.
Asking about pros and cons of such methods is not a matter of opinion.
This is what I am asking.

Asking which method is preferable, based on such pros and cons, is a matter of opinion.
This is not what I am asking.

---

I mean to use a `dict` (or a similar object) in Google apps script, with arrays as keys.
These (I didn't know) are converted to strings when used as dict keys.

The way I wrote my code, for what I needed, was working.
After I added some functionality, the limitations surfaced.
For instance, I want keys to be something like `[<color>,<number>]`.
Then I mean to do

```
for (key in mydict) {
    var c = key[0];
    var n = key[1];
    ... work separately with c as a string and n as a number
}
```

I guess I could split `key` at the comma, and convert `n` to int, but if there is a less cumbersome alternative, I would go for that.
Plus, in a more general case the conversion of `key` back to its original type may be more involved.

One solution I found is with [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).
I am currently trying it.

Regardless the fact it may work, is there any alternative?
What are possible pros and cons of those other options?

It would be very good to know before rewriting all code.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `dict`. It has ordinary objects and `Map`.

Comment: Object keys are always strings. What's wrong with converting the array to a string? If you want it to keep the mapping when you modify the array, that's more difficult.

Comment: Then use an object

Comment: @Barmar - Please see EDIT

Comment: @Cooper - I don't understand what are you proposing.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested objects.

```
mydict = {
    "color1": {
        1: <somevalue>,
        5: <othervalue>
    },
    "color2": {
        3: <value3>,
        10: <value4>
    }
};
```

Then use nested loops:

```
Object.entries(mydict).forEach(([c, item]) =>
    Object.entries(item).forEach([n, value]) => {
        // do something with c, n, value
    })
);
```

Comment: If object keys are always using strings, should I use `Number(n)` here as well?

Comment: Yes, if you need to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is

```
for (keystr in mydict) {
    var key = keystr.split(',');
    var c = key[0];
    var n = Number(key[1]);
    ... work separately with c as a string and n as a number
}
```

which works as long as none of the elements in the keys contain `','`.